# Why does the time measured by pytorch profiler exceed the time measured using time.time?

Tags: graph, pytorch, profiler, gnn

code 1：

```py
with torch.profiler.profile(activities=[torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CPU, torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CUDA]) as prof
```

code 2：
(detail https://xfxuezhang.blog.csdn.net/article/details/132600645):

```py
torch.cuda.current_stream(self._device).synchronize()
time.time()
```

result：

```py
code 1: 
    Self CPU time total: 71.297s
    Self CUDA time total: 16.971s
code 2: 52.260056
```

The time difference between these two is quite large.
Claude tells me：

> 1. The profiler measures the total running time of the program, including initialization and other overhead. time usually only
>    measures the core computation.
> 2. The profiler introduces additional overhead like recording events, collecting performance data, etc. This adds to the running time.
> 3. The profiler may affect program execution, e.g. causing more memory allocations or function calls, increasing running time.
> 4. The profiler time may include synchronization time like communication between processes. time only measures the process's own
>    running time.
> 5. The profiler accounts for all CUDA operations like memory copies, kernel launches, etc. time only measures CPU execution time.
> 6. The profiler has higher precision, accurate to microseconds. time only has millisecond resolution.
> 7. If using cProfile, it counts function calls not time, so the two metrics aren't comparable.
> 8. The profiler may measure more threads like I/O threads, while time only measures the main thread. In summary, the profiler provides more
>    comprehensive timing which is often longer than simple time
>    measurements. The profiler overhead needs to be analyzed for the
>    specifics of the program. torch.cuda.synchronize() can be used to
>    reduce discrepancies for CUDA operations.

But I don't know whether it answers correctly.

Besides, I use `with torch.profiler.record_function("train")` after `with torch.profiler.profile(activities=[torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CPU, torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CUDA]) as prof`, and I find that if i comment `record_function`, the final CPU time will decrease (~20s). I don't know why its overhead is so high.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not use the comments space for adding info - edit & update your post instead.